# Joining rows of a table one after another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have three tables A, B and C.

**Table C**

```
ID1 ID2    
1   10    
2   15    
3   18
```

**Table A**

```
ID1 Name    
1   John    
2   Jon    
3   William    
10  Willy    
15  Jack    
18  George
```

**Table B**

```
ID2 Address    
1   abc    
2   def    
3   ghi    
10  jkl    
15  mno    
18  pqr
```

I need the output such that each row from `Table C` comes one after another with corresponding names from their respective tables like below:

**Expected Output**

```
ID Name  Address    
1  John  abc    
10 Willy jkl    
2  Jon   def    
15 Jack  mno    
so on...
```

Here, `ID2` is the `foreign key`.

I tried doing a `UNION` but it is first giving all the records corresponding to the `ID1` and then `ID2`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by your question... what do you mean by "each row from table C comes one after another"?  Are you simply talking about `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 1):

Using CTE:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT c.ID1 As Order1, 1 as Order2, a.ID1, A.Name, b.Address
    FROM a
    INNER JOIN b
        ON a.ID1 = B.ID2
    INNER JOIN c
        ON c.ID1 = a.ID1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.ID1 As Order1, 2 as Order2, a.ID1, A.Name, b.Address
    FROM  a
    INNER JOIN b
        ON a.ID1 = B.ID2
    INNER JOIN c
        ON c.ID2 = a.ID1
)
SELECT ID1, Name, Address
FROM CTE
ORDER by order1, Order2
```

Comment: Simplest of all. no extra `row_number`, no extra joins.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below

```
SELECT i.id, i.NAME, i.address 
FROM   (SELECT 1 A, 
               Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY i.id1) ordr, 
               ID, 
               A.NAME, 
               B.address 
        FROM   tablec i 
               INNER JOIN TableA A 
                       ON i.id1 = A.id1 
               INNER JOIN TableB B 
                       ON i.id1 = B.id2 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2 A, 
               Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY i.id1) ordr, 
               i.id2 ID, 
               A.NAME, 
               B.address 
        FROM   tablec i 
               INNER JOIN TableA A 
                       ON i.id2 = A.id1 
               INNER JOIN TableB B 
                       ON i.id2 = B.id2) i 
ORDER  BY i.ordr, i.a
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT
    a.ID1 AS ID,
    a.Name,
    b.Address
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON b.ID2 = a.ID1
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT ID1, ID2
    FROM TableC
    WHERE
        ID1 = a.ID1
        OR ID2 = a.ID1
)c
ORDER BY
    c.ID1, a.ID1
```

**RESULT**

```
ID          Name       Address    ID1*        ID2*
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -----------
1           John       abc        1           10
10          Willy      jkl        1           10
2           Jon        def        2           15
15          Jack       mno        2           15
3           William    ghi        3           18
18          George     pqr        3           18
```

*`ID1` and `ID2` is included in the result for explanation.*

---

The `OUTER APPLY` will return the matching row from `TableC` which defines your order. You simple sort by `c.ID1` and `a.ID1`.